# How do I register a script with ScriptManger on partial postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I have a `RadGrid` within a `RadAjaxPanel` that has a View button that displays a user control in a jQuery popup, also within a `RadAjaxPanel`, that displays details of the grid record with a delete button. Clicking the delete button causes a partial postback that causes the record to be deleted and the grid to be rebound, removing the deleted record from it.

What I then need to do is run some client script to close the popup. I have tried:

```
private void RiskEditor_DeleteClick( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    this.grdRiskAnalysis.Rebind();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.RadAjaxPanelRiskEditor,
                                        this.RadAjaxPanelRiskEditor.GetType(),
                                        "closepopup",
                                        "delayClosePopup($j(this).closest('.ui-dialog'), 1000);",
                                        true);
}
```

In this example, `RadAjaxPanelRiskEditor` is the `AjaxPanel` that the User Control is in, but I have also tried registering the script with the panel that the grid is in. Neither works.

Can someone explain where I am going wrong and how to achieve this?

Thanks

Stewart

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I will do:

- I would use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock, since the RegisterStartupScript, according to msdn: "Registers a startup script block for **every** asynchronous postback".

If that does not work, there are some client js from ms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397536 and you can use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810.aspx - **Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager endRequest**, that will execute a specific js code, so maybe you can put your close dialog code there, with some conditional logic.